# How to exclude a project from CICD on Azure DevOps?

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I am new to CICD, Azure DevOps. I am trying to implement CICD to Asp .Net Web API project using Azure Devops. I saw few videos on internet and started implementing it. I am done with some standerd CI part but the build is always failing because of one project in a source solution.

So Is there any way to exclude a project from build?

I haven't written .yml file by myself it is auto generated by Azure Devops.

Actually I need a way to exclude a file from .yml file from azure buil pipeline. I tried the following code but still Test.cs is included in build.

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - QA
  paths:
    exclude:
    - Test/Test.cs
```

Comment: This exclude is under the trigger, so only will exclude the changes in the Test/Test.cs to trigger the CI, but if anything else triggers the CI the configured build process will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can pass the ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment as a parameter to MSBuild. Combining that with the SkipExtraFilesOnServer does the trick.

```
/p:Configuration=Debug
/p:DeployOnBuild=True
/p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish
/p:MsDeployServiceUrl=OurDevWebServer/msdeployagentservice
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True
/p:MSDeployPublishMethod=RemoteAgent
/p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True
/p:DeployIisAppPath=umbraco_TestSite
/p:IgnoreDeployManagedRuntimeVersion=True
/p:SkipExtraFilesOnServer=True
/p:ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment="media;App_Data\Logs;App_Data\preview"
/p:IncludeSetAclProviderOnDestination=False
/p:AuthType=NTML /p:UserName=
```

OR

Use an MS Build project file. 
[Create an MSBuild project file from scratch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/walkthrough-creating-an-msbuild-project-file-from-scratch?view=vs-2017)

And the at the build solution step in VSTS, select or type the project file path instead of the solution file. You will have to remove it down the road though. The maintenance tasks tend to be hard and counter-intuitive whenever the code base grows quickly. Visual Studio will not warn you if you have build errors (like obsolete path) in the MS Build project file.